# Is int32 a polymorphism of object?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

When i do

```
int k=3;
```

where in the reflector can i find the pseudo statement?

```
Object k = new Int32();
```

where can i find the value assign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though primitive types inherit from Object, the .net Framework treats them in a special way. An int is an int and treated using functions like ldc.i4 (loads a 32-bit constant onto the stack).

In situations where an object is needed, an int is indeed cast to Object through a process called [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No such statement exists.

`Int32` is an immutable value type.
`3` itself **is** an `Int32` value.

Comment: but all inherits from object , so there has to be some polymorphism mechanism here....

Comment: int32 does not inherit from object.  But it can boxed into an object

Comment: Only for *boxed* value types.

Comment: @Mid: Your (incorrect) statement has no bearing on your question.

Comment: @thorkia : Actually, it does. Int32 inherits from ValueType; ValueType inherits from Object. But, the compiler & CLR treats ValueType derived classes as special cases.

Comment: @Mid, by `no such statement exists`, @SLaks probably means that `Int32` has no public constructor, and as such you cannot invoke `new` on it. You can box and unbox (*debox?* ;) primitive types using explicit casts: `int k = (int) (Int32) 3;`

Comment: Fredric : sorry to tell you but i can do object x  = new int32(). ive just tried

Comment: @Mid, yup you're right, I just tested also: you can't do `new Int32(42)` but you *can* do `new Int32()`. My bad, I must be getting tired.

Comment: Fredric : so there is a mechanism of polymorphism here ... am i right ?

Comment: thanks for all , i checked with reflector. it does have the polymorphism mechanism , and the proof is the virtual gethashcode / tostring from object which is overriden by int32 type. so the initiation starts from object down to int32.